# macOS 上の Unity が音声ファイルのインポート中にクラッシュしてしまう

Tags: macos, unity3d

UnityがWindowsでは起動するがMacで起動しなくなり調べても原因がわからず困っており投稿いたしました。

クラッシュするようになった原因手順ですが

GitHubを使用しWindowsにて開発
↓
IosでビルドするためにMacPCで作業、GitHubでクローンしUnityを立ち上げる
↓
Unity起動中、BGMの読み込み部分で起動中から画面が進まず
↓
なので一旦、起動で止まっているBGMとSEをWindows消し
再びMacで起動するとUnityが無事に立ち上がった
↓
BGMが原因だと分かったのでmacで起動後に後入れでBGM.mp3を入れる方法をとることに
↓
クラッシュする

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上が今起こっていることです。
そもそも何故BGM読み込みでUnityが立ち上がらなくなったのかよく分かりません。

#### 動かなくなった原因 (推察)

過去にBGMの設定をWindowsのUnityで弄っていたので設定を変更する前のブランチに戻して試すも動かず。
その前まではMacでも動いていました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上です、個人的にメタファイルが壊れたと思っているのですがWindowsで立ち上がるのでおかしいなと思っております。同じことになった人原因がわかる方いましたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 追記

以下の画像で止まってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Unityの再インストールは試しました。

また、リネームもしてみました、手順は
Windowsの方で止まってしまうmp3をすべて消してからOK_SEだけを追加してからOK2_SE.mp3にリネームしコミットしました。
そのあと、macでプルし起動したらOK2_SE.mp3で起動が止まってしまいました。

SEファイルをすべて消した状態ならmacでもUnityが正常に立ち上がります。
macであとからSE追加するとUnityがクラッシュしてしまうといった状態です。

バージョンを追記します
Unity 2018.2.21f1

Comment: 別の音声ファイル（MP3)たどどうなりますか？簡単なMP３音声を作成して差し替えてみてください。できればmacで作成したMP3で試してみるのがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます、実際にmacで実際に追加してみましたが同じクラッシュログが表示されてしまいました。

Comment: macで新規にプロジェクトを作って、mp3を追加した場合はどうでしょうか？

Comment: 新規でプロジェクトを作成mp3を入れたら同じくクラッシュしました。
再インストールした記憶があるのですが、もう一度Unityをアンインストールしてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

バージョンが古かったようでUnity 2018.2.21f1から2018.4.14にバーションを上げたところ正常に動作しました。